# have (a) sequence identity of at least 90%

Tags: articles

Would you say the sentence below sounds natural without the indefinite article "a"?

> The protein must have (a) sequence identity of at least 90% with XXX.

Constructions like this usually take "a" as in

> The plane is travelling at a velocity of 900 m/s.
>
> Scotland has a population of 5,295,000.

and "have sequence identity of at least 90%" does not sit right with me but I often come across this usage. Any thoughts?

Comment: 'a sequence identity' is correct.

Comment: The question is whether *identity* is countable or uncountable in this usage.

Comment: Depending on how *sequence identity* is used in your field, consider "The protein must have at least 90% sequence identity with XXX".

Comment: Right. "..have 90% sequence identity" seems to work, though "..have a sequence identity of 90%" requires an indefinite article.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your example is something like 'correlation coefficient', so I'd use it the same way. "The two protein's base pairs must have a correlation coefficient of 0.9 or greater."

I think it's maybe a little more acceptable to drop the 'a' if you introduce a symbol, as in;

> The plane is travelling at velocity V[p] = 900m/s.

but I'm not really convincing myself here.